# Twitter cards for images direct links

Tags: twitter-card

I'm using shareX to upload my screenshots to a web server, and I would like to have Twitter cards working with my images direct links. I know this is possible because there are Twitter cards with Puu.sh direct links.

Answer (score 0):

Showing twitter card you need a hosted image and Add HTML meta tag on your page.

More detail available on Twitter Document.

Card Detail: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types

You can validate your card here: https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

Comment: I can't add meta tags because it's a direct link to the image like this : https://i.yopaman.fr/example-image.png, not an HTML page.

Comment: But Meta tag is important to show card. Without meta tag it is not  work